# NaN, Inf or invalid value detected in weights on Python Gaussian Inverse statsmodels GLM

Tags: python, nan, statsmodels, gaussian, glm

I'm running into an issue on a specific regression (GLM Inverse Gaussian) in Python that has worked previously with different data. Here is the example of the first data set throwing errors, and the same regression on different data. I can't isolate how to fix the issue. Interestingly, filtering different ranges of Grade will allow the regression to run without issue. For example, using only grades 4-11 will work, while 4-12 will not. See attached screenshot, the green highlighted ranges will work in the regression, the orange do not. For what it's worth, the issue persists in R as well. I've also tried manually changing some of the values to make the distribution not so bi-modal, this did not help.

[image: Green working grades]

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

###First dataset, errors thrown.        
data = {'Grade':['4', '5', '6', '7',    '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
        'Salary': ['13068','9353','12682','13526','15280', '18779.5', '23520',  '26010', '48231.5', '48510', '64400', '89250']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Grade', 'Salary'])
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].astype(int)
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].astype(float)
df.dtypes    
df.plot.scatter(x = 'Grade', y = 'Salary')

x = df['Grade']
y = df['Salary']
    
exog = sm.add_constant(x)
endog = y
    
model = sm.GLM(endog, exog, family = sm.families.InverseGaussian())
#errors thrown here
results = model.fit()

####### second data set, this data works on the GaussianInverse
data = {'Grade':['4', '5', '6', '7',    '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
        'Salary': ['29279', '33696.5', '36634', '42507', '43362.5', '45999.5', '53522', '61559.9', '69635','78734.5','91868.5','106071']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Grade', 'Salary'])
df2['Grade'] = df2['Grade'].astype(int)
df2['Salary'] = df2['Salary'].astype(float)
df2.dtypes
df2.plot.scatter(x = 'Grade', y = 'Salary')
        
 x = df2['Grade']
 y = df2['Salary']
        
 exog = sm.add_constant(x)
 endog = y
        
 model = sm.GLM(endog, exog, family = sm.families.InverseGaussian())
 #no errors on df2
 results = model.fit()
 y_pred = pd.DataFrame(results.predict(exog))
 print(results.summary())
```

Here is the error message:

```
C:\Users\%user%\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\families\links.py:319: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return np.power(z, 1. / self.power)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-842-89f6e4763922>", line 6, in <module>
    results = model.fit()

  File "C:\Users\%user%\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py", line 1027, in fit
    cov_kwds=cov_kwds, use_t=use_t, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\%user%\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\generalized_linear_model.py", line 1165, in _fit_irls
    check_weights=True)

  File "C:\Users\%user%Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\_tools.py", line 48, in __init__
    raise ValueError(self.msg.format('weights'))

**ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in weights, estimation infeasible.**
```

The R error on the same data is this:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(eta) : NaNs produced
```

Is there perhaps another method I need to try here?

Comment: In some cases, optimization is scale sensitive. You can try rescaling `Salary`, e.g. divide by 1000 to make it in thousand dollars. Also Gamma sometimes doesn't work well with the default canonical inverse link. Using log link makes optimization more robust in some cases.

Comment: Thanks @Josef for the suggestion. I tried rescaling Salary a few different ways and still no luck. I do have a log link regression as part of an algorithm (multiple transformation regressions are used on the same data and the "best" one is picked for further use down the script). So the issue is that the code stops when this error hits and the regressions after this one don't complete.